# Windows 10: How to track 'docker pull' traffic calls using fiddler

Tags: docker, fiddler, docker-for-windows

I am trying to run `docker run hello-world` from within the company network and its throwing an error:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> docker run hello-world
Unable to find image 'hello-world:latest' locally
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: Get https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/: net/http: request canceled while waiting for  onnection (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers).
See 'C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe run --help'.
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

when i type

`https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/`

on the browser it kind of works and throws the following

`{"errors":[{"code":"UNAUTHORIZED","message":"authentication required","detail":null}]}`

I suspect that our corporate firewall is blocking some call to `docker.io` as this works well when I am on my home network. I need to find out the actual call blocking so that I can request the IT team to open this up.

I tried to use fiddler to see what is going on, but fiddler is not capturing any traffic on the docker calls. As I am really new to docker, I can't really figure out how to setup fiddler to capture docker http(s) calls.

Any pointers will help.

Comment: If it just times out then execute "netstat -n" and see if any sockets in SYN_SENT state which will indicate that firewall is blocking connection. Fiddler will not show any more then that either if SSL port is blocked.